# Rename a Google sheet tab based on cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I partially know the name of 2 sheets I need to rename when the cell `B2` change in each sheet:

- One in called `csv_nat` and it should be renamed to `csv_nat_30_11_2019` when cell `B2` in sheet changes (it is a date format like 30/11/2019)
- The other one has the exact same structure and is called `csv_alt`

My main issue is the following. When the tab name has already changed, I need to locate the sheet from its root name (`csv_nat`) and I have not figured out how.

My limited and starting code for now is:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() != "B2") return;
  e.source.getActiveSheet().setName("csv_nat_"+e.value);
}
```

Besides, does the `onEdit` function work for any change or only when user edits the cell?

Comment: Looking at your existing code, it seems you only want to edit the sheet that was edited. You're kind of already doing that (`e.range.getSheet()` would be better), so why exactly do you need to locate the sheet by tab name?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate your `csv_nat` or `csv_alt` sheets, you can use **regex** in this case.

### Try this example

*if sheet contains csv_nat or csv_alt it will alert you*:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if(ss.getSheetName().match(/csv_nat|csv_alt/)){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Working Sheet is found")
}
```

### Reference

- [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)